# Fancybox single image loading fails on IE

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, fancybox

Using Fancybox single image box, the image is not completely loaded in IE. Chrome loads the image perfectly, but on IE it looks like as the loading is cut short somehow. The image itself comes from DB as byte array and loads just fine on IE when set as an ordinary html image.

This is what I get on Fancybox:
[image]

Any pointers on how to force the loading to continue until the whole image is sent?

**Edit**

JQuery for fancybox:

```
$("a#single_image").fancybox({
    'type': 'image',
    'hideOnContentClick' : 'true'
});
```

Image:

```
<a id="single_image" href="<%= Source %>"><img runat="server" id="largeImg" /></a>
```

Where "Source" is a string containing the image data.

Comment: Which IE version r u using? and which fancy box version r u using?

Comment: IE 11.0.9 and Fancybox 1.3.4

Comment: Use Fancy box v=2.1.5 it will solve your problem..

Comment: Tried, had no effect.

Comment: What html/js code are you using?

Comment: Show your HTML/JS Code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself after scratching my head for a really long time.
Turns out the request grows too long for IE to handle (or something like it) when the image data is read twice from the code-behind.
Instead I removed the `href` attribute from the `<a>`-tag and added it again with jQuery, so that it's read from the `<img>`-tag's `src` attribute, like so:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var src = $("#<%: largeImg.ClientID %>").attr("src");
    $("#largeImgLink").attr("href", src);
 });
```

This also keeps the request shorter and reduces traffic load on the server.
On a footnote, this was **not** a Fancybox-specific issue. The problem was the same with Lightbox also, and only on IE and EDGE. Chrome loaded the image correctly from the beginning.